# How to create a boxplot not showing the outliers using Python and Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

How to create a boxplot not showing the outliers using Python and Plotly?

I have a full list of points I use to create a box plot that has many outliers and the range is too big for a comparable box plot.

I just don't want to show the outliers in this list on the box plot at all.

1. Is there a way to not show outliers in the box plot?

If not, then I tried removing the outliers from data before plotting it. However, then Plotly makes some of points that I did not remove as outliers.

2. Is there a way to create a box plot where none of the elements are considered outliers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Andrew from Plotly here.

1. You can't just *not* show some of the data in the array. So you can set `boxpoints: "all"` to get a jitter of the points, including the outliers. This will leave the boxplot as-is, without outliers sitting on top of it. I'm guessing this isn't really what you want though.
2. To prevent outliers from being discovered in the data array, set `boxpoints: false`

So in Python, something like this should work:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import Box, Figure

fig = Figure()
boxpoints_default = Box(y=[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 10], name='default')
boxpoints_false = Box(y=[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 10], boxpoints=False, name='no outliers')
boxpoints_all = Box(y=[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 10], boxpoints='all', name='jitter boxpoints')

fig['data'].extend([boxpoints_default, boxpoints_false, boxpoints_all])
fig['layout'].update(title='Comparing boxplot "boxpoints" settings')

py.iplot(fig, filename='Stack Overflow 31497537')
```

Here's the resulting figure for that:

https://plot.ly/~theengineear/4936/comparing-boxplot-boxpoints-settings/

Here's a link to box plot tutorials in general with Plotly:

http://help.plot.ly/make-a-box-plot/

Comment: Is it possible to cut the data points identified by plotly as outliers before plotting the graph? Or rather: Why can't I tell plotly to *not* show some of the data? I do of course understand the moral implications of cutting out the outliers, but is that a choice plotly should do for me?

Comment: @theengineear Andrew, this is not a solution. Those options resize the Whiskers. The only option that would produce what OP wants is `marker=dict(opacity=1)`. And although it works, if you have a large number of outliers, simply excluding them would be more peformance-optimal.

Comment: @Ufos, you're right. Adjusting the opacity is the only workaround I could find for this frustratingly simple issue. However, the correct setting should be `marker=dict(opacity=0)` for anyone wondering.  Why does plotly make it so hard to do such simple things...

Comment: Well, the official dev prefers to ignore the problem, so, emh, it's hard *shrug*. Thanks for correction!

Answer (score 5):

Late to the game but I found a (perhaps new) easy solution:

```
fig.update_traces(boxpoints=False)
```

as shown here: https://plotly.com/python/reference/box/

Note that I had to delete the `selector=dict(type='box)` section as it created an error.